# AHK script for sending hotkeys to specific window

Tags: script, autohotkey

i need an ahk script that sends 3 different hotkeys ( pressing f1 , sending f5 for example to the active window of a specific (poker) application ) f1 has to be f1 for other applications running parallel though

who can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the title of your poker application always ends with `- NLH`, but you don't want to match those windows whose class is `PokerStarsTableFrameClass`, use the following:

```
F1::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "- NLH$") AND (Class != "PokerStarsTableFrameClass"))
    SendPlay {F5}
else
    SendPlay {F1}
return
```

#### How it works

- `WinGet(Title|Class), (Title|Class), A` reads the active (`A`) window's title|class and stores it in the variable `Title|Class`.
- `- NLH$` is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) matching all strings that end with `- NLH`. (`$` is the end of string)
- `if (RegExMatch(Title, "- NLH$") AND (Class != "PokerStarsTableFrameClass"))` tests if the regular expression matches `Title`, **but** the `Class` is different from the exception.

  - If so, `SendPlay {F5}` sends <kbd>F5</kbd> to the active window.
  - Otherwise, `SendPlay {F1}` sends a normal <kbd>F1</kbd> to the active window.

Comment: thx a lot works for the app but disables hotkeys on another app even though "NLH" which i used instead of "poker" isnt in the window title, cannot use window class as another app has the same class, but is it possible to exclude a ahk_class ( "PokerStarsTableFrameClass" ) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: thx again found also help in the autohotkey community chat . this works very good so far:                              `code`SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive NLH
    F1::SendPlay {F5}
    F2::SendPlay {F6}
    F3::SendPlay {F7}
#IfWinActive
return

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an AutoHotkey script. You need to learn how to use the available API (commands) to achieve what you want. To send input directly to a window or its controls, active or not, you can use the [ControlSend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) command.